# How can `string.Empty` be hashed?

Tags: c#, .net, string, hash, cryptography

For some reason this doesn't make sense to me. How is an empty `string` hashed when there are no `char`s in the `string` to hash?

What I'm talking about would look like this:

```
System.Web.Helpers.Crypto.HashPassword(string.Empty);
```

How is this possible?

Comment: In general, hash functions process data by updating some internal state. If there is no data to process, then the final state is the same as the initial state.

Comment: How can string.empty.length be calculated if there are no characters to count?

Comment: In this case short strings (including the empty string) will simply be padded with 0x00 bytes until it's 64 bytes long, and then it gets hashed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto.hashpassword%28v=vs.111%29.aspx):

> The password hash is generated with the RFC 2898 algorithm using a 128-bit salt, a 256-bit subkey, and 1000 iterations. The format of the generated hash bytestream is {0x00, salt, subkey}, which is base-64 encoded before it is returned.

First you need to understand how [RFC 2898 works](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt). In a nutshell it combines the salt with the passed in password, hashes it a number of times, and produces a bytestream that you can read out as many bytes as you want.

Using the above quoted documentation we see that it picks a random salt that is 128 bits large, uses 1000 hashes, and pulls 256 bits out of the stream at the end.

So we can get chars out because RFC 2898 allows you to take as many bytes as you want to from the output of the function, it is not a fixed output. We also get a different output if we call `Crypto.HashPassword(string.Empty);` twice because it chooses a new random salt every time we call the function.

Comment: Also note that hash functions are still defined on empty input. For example, you can hash a zero-byte file or zero-length string, and they should give you the same output.

Comment: Most hash functions operate on blocks of data, incomplete blocks will be often padded with sets of 0 byte values to go to the next larger block size. However see the specification for whatever hash you are interested in for the exact procedure, the above is just the general "what most of them do" guideline.